# See everybody changes in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

There is a link in teamcity that shows current's user changes (My Changes)

[image]

I want to see all changes from all users. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go on to the project home page, You have a tab `Change Log`. This will show you all the changes made by everyone.

[image: Just for reference]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Additionaly, the tab My Changes will be renamed to Changes in TeamCity 8.1 (which will be released in February), and it will allow to see recent changes either for all or a specific user.